# JS Universal apps "Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: javascript, rotation, winjs, win-universal-app

I am trying to set a rotation within MS Universal apps using the Javascript project.

But I am receiving the following error message

> >
>   0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference

I have looked through several error reports throughout the web and most of what I saw was that the element first has to be created but in my case it is, because the function is only executed when I set the value in the form
I also tried [setAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339119/unable-to-get-property-style-of-undefined-or-null-reference) but it gives the same message only with setattribute

HTML

```
<section>
    <p>Set rotation Value!</p>
    <input id="rotationInput" type="text" />
    <button id="setRotation">Set Rotation</button>
</section>
...
<section>
        <img class="rotateimg" src="images/logo.scale-100.png" />
</section>
```

default.js

```
args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function completed() {
...
   // Retrieve the button and register event handler. 
   var setRotation = document.getElementById("setRotation");
   setRotation.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler2, false);
};
...

function buttonClickHandler2(el) {
    var degrees = document.getElementById("rotationInput").value;
    document.getElementById("rotateimg").style.transform = "rotate(" + degrees + "deg)";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id is not the same as class, look at that

```
<img class="rotateimg" src="images/logo.scale-100.png" />
```

should be

```
<img id="rotateimg" src="images/logo.scale-100.png" />
```

or, alternatively

```
<img id="rotateimg" class="rotateimg" src="images/logo.scale-100.png" />
```

Comment: @veritaS - or alternatively, if you don't want/can't change the HTML, you can access one or more elements with a class with `document.getElementsByClassName("className")` just for reference. And @jperelli - yours is a kind of injection...the dream injection **XD**